# How to fix StdinNotImplementedError in sageMath

Tags: input, compiler-errors, user-input

I am beginner on sagemath and try to get input from user to work with graphs but it gives me error as I am using sagemath online server on cocalc.

The code I written is below

```
n = Integer(input("Enter the value of n (for Pn and Cn): "))
s = Integer(input("Enter the value of s (for Ks,t): "))
t = Integer(input("Enter the value of t (for Ks,t): "))
```

and the error generated is

**StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests.**

I tried using different input methods but error is still there.